# xUnit and FParsec "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: f#, xunit, fparsec

I am working my way through FParsec's tutorial but adjusting the code to run under xUnit.  When running this test:

```
open FParsec
open Xunit

exception ParseError of string
let parse parser input = 
    match run parser input with 
        | Success (result, _, _) -> result
        | Failure (error, _, _) -> raise (ParseError error) 

type UserState = unit
type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>

let str s = pstring s
let floatBetweenBrackets:Parser<_> = str "[" >>. pfloat .>> str "]"

[<Fact>]
let ``Parsing [1.0] works`` () =
    let r = parse floatBetweenBrackets "[1.0]"
    Assert.Equal(1.0,r)
```

I get this failure:

```
[23/10/17 13:31:53 Informational] ------ Run test started ------
[23/10/17 13:31:53 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.3299056] Received 1 results from 1 requests
[23/10/17 13:31:53 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.3306170]   Starting:    Experiments
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Error] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5309115]     fSharpExperiments.FParsecTest.Parsing [1.0] works [FAIL]
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5325011]       System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5356227]       Stack Trace:
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5360697]            at FParsec.CharParsers.applyParser[Result,UserState](FSharpFunc`2 parser, CharStream`1 stream)
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5364446]            at FParsec.CharParsers.run@97.Invoke(CharStream`1 stream)
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5367866]            at FParsec.CharStream.ParseString[T,TUserState](String chars, Int32 index, Int32 length, FSharpFunc`2 parser, TUserState userState, String streamName)
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5371211]            at FParsec.CharParsers.run[Result](FSharpFunc`2 parser, String string)
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5374329]         C:\Users\jackc\Documents\Git\fsharpExperiments\Experiments\FParsec.fs(28,0): at fSharpExperiments.FParsecTest.parse[a](FSharpFunc`2 parser, String input)
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5377692]         C:\Users\jackc\Documents\Git\fsharpExperiments\Experiments\FParsec.fs(54,0): at fSharpExperiments.FParsecTest.Parsing [1.0] works()
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.5479057]   Finished:    Experiments
[23/10/17 13:31:54 Informational] ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:00.604968) ==========
```

which is odd because it runs fine if I do this outside of the test function.

```
let r = parse floatBetweenBrackets "[1.0]"
Assert.Equal(1.0,r)
```

r is `float = 1.0` and `r = 1.0` is true.

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to be some kind of bug.  I added a new file to my project, containing the above with the same namespace but different module name from the original.  This new test fails but the original, unchanged one, passes.  It seems that I only get a failure when the file is the very last one in my project.